# Check a webpage every hour in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

I am wanting to code a script that checks a webpage every hour. I have been looking at other questions on SO, and everyone is talking about using:

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer t;
```

Can someone please help me?

I haven't done much coding in C# in a long time, as I have been looking at Unix & Linux lately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what did you tryed? no one here will give you completed solution if you don't show you have made something for your own

Comment: @harry180 Na, there always seems to be someone who will code it for them! But you'll loose reputation on the question OP.

Comment: @weston, I understand, but I should've tried it first myself. I understand why I am getting these downvotes, it was my mistake. Thanks everyone for helping. I did search Google though, but nothing (that I could see) helped me, otherwise I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: @weston that's sad but true :(

Comment: @Sam Point taken, I'll remove the comment. The way he asked the question made me think he was basically asking "How do Timers work", which is apparently not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Timers;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromHours(1).TotalMilliseconds);
        t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // This code will execute every hour
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                // Send an HTTP request to download the contents of the web page
                string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");

                // do something with the results
                ...
            }
        };
        Console.WriteLine("press any key to stop");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```